# Can an iPhone app modify data in iOS, which designate the location(spot) of other apps' icons on the phone's screen?

Tags: ios, icons

I am considering to study the Swift and am thinking of creating an app for my iPhone, for only personal interest. To expand my idea, I need to know this....

Can an app get(read) data from iOS like absolute coordinate numbers of location of other apps' icons on the home screen ?

if so, can an app modify the location coordinate numbers to change(move) the other apps' icons to other places on the home screen ?

Thanks

Comment: No. Apps have limited access to system settings on iOS. Modifying the home screen isn't possible.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, can I ask a quick question?  Following your reply, there is a only one way to move apps' icons to other places on the home screen by dragging icons  using human fingers, is that right ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the only way, yeah.